# Using PDFsharp to open AES 128-bit encrypted files

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf

I've been receiving pdf files that I have been processing with the PDFsharp libraries. These files where 128-bit RC4 encrypted. Now I getting files that are 128-bit AES encyption.

I'm getting this exception "The PDF document is protected with an encryption not supported by PDFsharp."

Is AES just not supported, or do I need to change the method in which I open the file?

```
     Using InDoc As PdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(InputFileName, Password, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)
            Using OutDoc As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument
                For Each page As PdfPage In InDoc.Pages
                    OutDoc.AddPage(page)
                Next
            End Using
  End Using
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDFsharp does not support AES for Adobe 7+ yet.