# What are encryptions supported by PDFSharp?

Tags: c#, encryption, pdfsharp

I tried to open a PDF in `PDFSharp` with **128bit RC4** encryption and also **256bit AES** encryption both have thrown me error

> **The PDF document is protected with an encryption not supported by PDFsharp**.

I have no luck in finding out the what all are supported encryption standards in PDFSharp.

I used the line below to open the pdf

```
 PdfDocument pdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(new MemoryStream(bytes));
```

**Edit**

Since a possible duplicate has been added to this question.

Linked queston answers just
 that **AES is not Supported**

What I am looking for is can anyone list **supported Encryptions**. Since Both RC4 and AES i tried is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using PDFsharp to open AES 128-bit encrypted files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829707/using-pdfsharp-to-open-aes-128-bit-encrypted-files)

Comment: @iankemp I have explained why my question is not a duplicate of the question you have listed. As it doesn't answer my question.